# Is there a difference between Kernel parameters and the bootloader parameters?

Tags: boot, grub2, network-interface, pxe, kernel-parameters

I often see editing of grub2 parameters to change kernel parameters (i.e. loglevel, quiet, intremap, etc...), but I think there are also grub2 parameters and I'm lost to what they actually are.

Specifically, does grub2 need any special parameters to handle a network boot (PXE)? In legacy-grub, I've had to add macappend but I'm not sure if this is a kernel parameter or if it something for the grub configuration.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are the same, the main difference is that kernel parameters can be set in three ways :

1- During the boot sequence **GRUB** via :

```
  a- The Grub interface during the boot.
  b- Configuration files with regenerating `grub.cfg` (permanent)
```

2- During the **RunTime** via :

```
sysctl command 
/proc/sys/* directory
```

3- By configuring and compiling the kernel from `source`.

Also don't confuse the GRUB properties with the ones on top, they are proper to GRUB , like :

```
Change the boot order.
Customize the grub menu / entries.
Change the default boot timeout.
```

Finally to boot from **PXE** you should have a network interface that support it and configure the server to boot from it on the **BIOS**.